# If conditionals does not work in cordova barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs

```
var status = true;
if (code===8) {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function (result) {
      if( result.cancelled === false || result.cancelled === 0) {

        var jsonResponse = NewMobile.app.GetCustomerCard(result.text);

        if (jsonResponse.ResponseMessage !== '' ) {
          status = false;
        }

        if (value > parseFloat(jsonResponse.CardBalance)) {
          status = false;                                 
        }

        if(value > parseFloat(jsonResponse.RemainingDayLimit)) {
           status = false;
        }
      }
    },
    function (error) {
       alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
  );
}

alert(status);
```

All conditionals makes status false but it still alert true.How can I fix it?I m using sencha touch developing in extJs.using cordova barcodeScanner if conditional does not work syncron.

Comment: How do you know that if statements "do not work"? Did you try to debug your code, like print the variables, see which blocks are executed?

Comment: how can I debug on mobile?It use CordovaPlugin.

Comment: Depends which IDE and which kind of mobile you use. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/

Comment: Try to keep result in some variable, and then alert it, maybe the problem is with your first if

Answer (score 0):

2 way for debug application

-Using android-emulator
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

-Using emulator for android studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/

1)Install APK in to device

2)Connect device to PC

3)Open remote device option for google chrome
(How to open remote device option
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ )

4)Click on inspect button then open new window for debug